# How to set environment variables for GUI program?

Tags: bash, gui, environment-variables

I am using texstudio, a latex editor, on Ubuntu 14.04. When I start it from bash `$ texstudio`, and click the compile button, it works fine. However, if I start it by clicking the icon in the launcher, I receive

```
Error: Could not start the command: xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode
```

I know the reason is that in the settings, the build command is set to `latex -src -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`, so it can be found if texstudio is opened from bash, since it inherits the environment variables I set in `.bashrc`: `export PATH=/my/path/to/latex:$PATH`.

My question is, is there a file in which I can set the environment variables for GUI programs?

Comment: tl;dr: add `PATH DEFAULT=/my/path/to/latex:${PATH}` to `~/.pam_environment`, and re-login.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Launching_desktop_application_with_an_environment_variable